# how do you build independent UI

Tags: user-interface

I mean how do you build your own UI most applications I see are unique and have their own independent UI not using existing libraries or UI kits they are simply their own in the sense that they are unique and the developer has complete control over the appearance. In particular a windows user interface program

Comment: What platform are you trying to build on, please @Gonja ?

Comment: Desktop and also how to implement animations

Comment: What development environment do you have please?

Comment: visual studio and am fluent in c++ but I mostly learnt to develop console programs now I would like to shift to building UI programs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've told me, @Gonja, This would be the best way to start:

Open Visual Studio and create a new project.

- From the languages dropdown, select 'C++'.
- Choose 'Windows Desktop Wizard'.
- Give your project a name and location.
- From the 'Windows desktop project', 'Application type' dropdown, select 'Desktop Application'

Then you will have a new C++ project with all the objects to create a window application.

Just to note, this is not a particularly good question for stackoverflow, so I hope you can read this answer before it's closed by an administrator.